# (class)this.method and super.method in java

Tags: java, methods, super

So I have two methods one in a superclass and one in a subclass with the same name and parameters lets say public void method(). I have also another method in the subclass called method1() as follows:

```
public void method1() 
{super.method();}
```

The code above when executed it goes as planned (the method1 is using the method from the superclass) BUT if I change it to this:

```
public void method1() 
{((Class)this).method();}
```

Where Class is the name of the superclass for some reason it does not use the superclass method but the method of the subclass with the same name. Isn't super the same thing with ((Class)this)? Why does this happen?

EDIT: This is the actual class (I added the actual code so my problem is more clear)

```
public class MWindow extends Window
{
  private String message = "No message";
  protected int size = 7;
  public MWindow(String message)
  {
   size = 2;
   this.message = message;
   System.out.println ("Window message = " + message);
  }
  public MWindow(int size, String message)
  {
   super(size);
   this.message = message;
   System.out.println ("Window message = " + message);
  }
  public void setSize1(int y)
  {size = y;}
  public void setSize2(int z)
  {super.setSize (z);}
  public void printSize()
  {System.out.println ("MSize="+size);}
  public void printSize1()
  {System.out.println(((Window)this).size);} 
  public void printSize2()
  {((Window)this).printSize();} 
}
```

This is the superclass

```
public class Window
{
  protected int size;
  public Window()
  {
  size=1;
  System.out.println("Window size="+size);
  }
  public Window(int size)
  {
  this.size=size;
  System.out.println("Window size="+size);
  }
  public void setSize(int x)
  {size += x;}
  public void printSize()
  {System.out.println("Size=" + size);}
}
```

This is the main() class

```
 public class RunWindow
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
   Window w1=new Window();
   Window w2=new Window(2);
   System.out.println(w1.size);
   System.out.println(w2.size);
   MWindow mw1=new MWindow("First MWindow");
   MWindow mw2=new MWindow(3, "Second MWindow");
   System.out.println(mw1.size);
   System.out.println(mw2.size);
   mw1.setSize1(4);
   System.out.println(mw1.size);
   mw1.setSize2(2);
   System.out.println(mw1.size);
   mw1.setSize(2);
   System.out.println(mw1.size);
   w1.printSize();
   mw1.printSize();
   mw1.printSize1();
   mw1.printSize2(); 
  }
}
```

Executing the above we get:

```
Window size=1
Window size=2
1 
2
Window size=1
Window message = First MWindow
Window size=3
Window message = Second MWindow
2
7
4
4
4
Size=1
MSize=4
5
MSize=4
```

The problem is that at the last result it should be Size=5 instead of MSize=4 since the superclass printSize method is called and not the printSize method of the subclass.

Comment: What is {((Class)this).method();}????. It is better If you post complete your classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how polymorphism works (and its [late-binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) mechanism). It doesn't take type of reference into account, but actual type of instance.

That is why your `((SuperClass)this).method();` will behave same as `this.method()`.

> Isn't super the same thing with ((SuperClass)this)?

So no, `super` and `((SuperClass)this)` are not the same.

Via `super.method()` you are moving flow of control to code of `method()` available for superclass, but via `(SuperClass)this` you are just casting reference.

Comment: What do you mean by "casting reference"? I am trying to understand the use of a ((Class)this).method() syntax

Comment: We can think of `this` as special kind of reference. Just like in case of `Cat cat = new Cat()` `cat` is reference which can be cast to `Animal` like `Animal animal = (Animal)cat` which creates new reverence of type `Animal`. But even if we do it and we will invoke `animal.eat()` code of `Cat#eat()` method will be invoked because of late binding. Similar thing happens here, but instead of `cat` we have `this`.

Comment: I still can't understand how it works. I am sorry I am new to java. What I don't understand is how the reference part works. I have a method in a subclass that refers to it. If I put ((Class)this).method() the reference changes from the subclass to the class named Class? And what happens when the reference changes in terms of output?

Comment: I am not sure where should I start explaining. Did you read article about late binding I included in my answer? If no then short form is that: binding (choosing which body of method to use) for non private, static, nor final methods happens at runtime (it is late binding) not at compilation time (early binding). What this means is that for regerences `Animal a1 = new Cat();` `Animal a2 = new Dog();` when you call `a1.eat();` `a2.eat()` it will invoke for `a1` body of `Cat#eat()` and for `a2` `Dog#eat()`. That is what polymorphism is about.

Comment: When you are doing `((SuperClass)this).method()` you can think of it as doing `SuperClass sc = (SuperClass)this;` `sc.method()`, but as explained earlier type of reference is not important, and body of `method` will be decided based on actual type of instance which `sc` holds (instance type doesn't change, only reference which you used to store it did).

Comment: Ok so in my example when I write ((Window)this).printSize() all I did in fact is to change the reference from MWindow type to Window type but the method that will be called is the one contained in the class used as instance type (in this case MWindow) since as you said instance type is not changed and thus I get this result?

Comment: Yes, seems right. But you need to remember that only methods are polymorphic, fields are not. So if your superclass and subclass will have field with same name like `class Super{ int x = 1;} class Sub extends Super{ int x = 2;}` for `Super s = new Sub(); System.out.println(s.x)` will print `1`, not `2` despite the fact that instance stored in `s` is of type `Sub`.

Answer (score 0):

No, in short what `(Class)this` is doing is converting the type of the reference the subclass to the superclass but the class that is referenced remains the same. Now in general if you have a reference of type  that points to a  and you call a method that  overrides, the expected behaviour is to get the overridden method. So `(Class)this` is therefore not different.